# Convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1+ 3\cos(n^2)}{7+2\sin^2n} \right)^{3n - \ln^2n}$

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

I need to examine convergence of that sum:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1+ 3\cos(n^2)}{7+2\sin^2n} \right)^{3n - \ln^2n}$$

I can rewrite it as:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\left(\frac{1+ 3\cos(n^2)}{7+2\sin^2n}\right)^{3n}}{\left(\frac{1+ 3\cos(n^2)}{7+2\sin^2n}\right)^{\ln^2n}}$$

But then, I can't even get:

$$\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} \left(\frac{1+ 3\cos(n^2)}{7+2\sin^2n} \right)^{3n - \ln^2n} = 0$$

I know that is true but I don't know how to transform that expression to do something with trigonometric functions (how to merege them).

Additionally, I know that ratio test won't help me once I am done with limit. Same for root test. I think that it will be hard to use Abel's and Dirichlet's since trigonometric functions will equal to something periodic ( $\neq $ monotonic).

Comment: Use `\sin` for $\sin$, `\cos` for $\cos$, and `\ln` for $\ln$.

Comment: Ok, I will edit that.

Comment: Try finding an upper bound for the numerator and a lower bound for the denominator and exponent.

Comment: I have changed the formatting of the title so as to [make it take up less vertical space](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9686/290189) -- this is a policy to ensure that the scarce space on the main page is distributed evenly over the questions.  See [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9730/290189) for more information. Please take this into consideration for future questions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sure, no problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply the [root test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_test)

We have
$$\underset{n\to \infty }{\text{lim}}\frac{3 n-\log ^2 n}{n}=3$$

and
$$\left| \frac{3 \cos \left(n^2\right)+1}{2 \sin ^2(n)+7}\right|\le \frac47 $$
$$L=\underset{n\to \infty }{\text{limsup}}\left(\left| \frac{3 \cos \left(n^2\right)+1}{2 \sin ^2(n)+7}\right| ^{3 n-\log ^2(n)}\right)^{1/n}=\frac{64}{343}$$

as $L<1$ the series converges absolutely.

Comment: Raffaele, Great Job.

Comment: I need to get more used to those common limits. I did't see that at all in the exponent. So I can always just put the upper estimation and evaluate limsup? Does it apply to all the tests or just Cauchy's root test (I applied only the standard limit version)

Answer (score 0):

You could also notice that that $3n-\ln^2 n > n$ for large $n.$ For such $n$ the terms of the series are bounded above by $(4/7)^n.$ Since $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (4/7)^n<\infty,$ the original series converges by the comparison test.